# Kivy Resize Window Not Working After Compiling

Tags: python, kivy, nuitka

I'm trying to disable window resizing/maximizing on my Python app with its layout built from a .kv file. In this code and my .ini file, resizing is disabled. But after I compile via Nuitka, resizing works from the .exe file. Anything I may be missing?

```
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.logger import LoggerHistory
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Image, PhotoImage, Tk, ttk
from tkinter import Label as tkinterlabel
from uac import admin, is_admin, rerun_as_admin
import ctypes
import logging
import os
import platform
import re
import shutil
import socket
import subprocess
import time
import winreg as wrg
import wmi
import yaml
```

`os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)) _local_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

```
    Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
    Builder.load_file(_local_dir + '/kivy.kv')
    Window.resizable = False
    Window.size = (500, 700)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using --standalone or --onefile options in Nuitka, they may be looking at a different copy of the config settings.
If you get the correct behavior without --standalone or --onefile, then start digging through the .dist folder to make sure you are looking at the correct file of config settings.

Also double check that you are running the correct .exe file and not an old version. --standalone puts the executable file in a different location than --follow-imports and if you are copy-pasting your test commands, you will get the wrong one.

Comment: Thank you, will look at that. This is my code:

python -m nuitka --mingw64 --standalone --onefile --experimental=use_pefile --experimental=use_pefile_recurse --experimental=use_pefile_fullrecurse --remove-output --assume-yes-for-downloads --enable-plugin=tk-inter --include-data-file=*.kv=./ --include-data-file=*.png=./  --include-data-file=*.mp3=./ --include-data-file=*.yaml=./ --onefile-tempdir-spec=C:\Folder\onefile_%PID%_%TIME% --output-dir=C:\Folder main.py

Comment: Your configuration is a bit different than what I do, so I can't confirm if your code is right or wrong, but I can give you a few things to think about. I don't think you need both --standalone and --onefile. Do you have a main.dist folder? Does it have a file with the Window.resizable = False setting?